# How to add the name of each row, when I use select command

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with the name and date added.

How do I make a request so that the output contains names, the number of unique names,the minimum and maximum date of addition.

Here you get only the total number - I need for each unique name.

```
SELECT COUNT(namesh) AS count1
     , MAX(dates) AS maxx
     , MIN (dates) AS minn 
  FROM testtable11 
 WHERE namesh IS NOT NULL
```

When I add the namesh to SELECT I get "not a single-group group function"

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Group BY namesh to your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(namesh) AS count1, MAX(dates) AS maxx, MIN(dates) AS minn 
FROM testtable11 
WHERE namesh IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY namesh
```

not a single-group group function
error occurs when a query has an aggregate function (e.g. COUNT, MIN, MAX, SUM, or AVG) as well as other fields or statements, but there is no GROUP BY clause.